# Will the code after sendRedirect() still be executed?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm curious how sendRedirect() works after it redirects.

**MaintenanceController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String menu(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    if((new BaseController()).checkPrivilege(request) == "ADMIN") {
        return (new BaseController()).fallback(request, response);
    }
    return "maintenance/menu";
}
```

**BaseController.java**

```
public String fallback(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    return String.format("redirect:%s",request.getHeader("referer"));
}

public String checkPrivilege(HttpServletRequest request) {
     return (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("privilege");
}
```

It's not like I could just put system.out.print() after the sendRedirect() to print something if it would execute immediately after. I would like to know if *at some point in time* it will still execute the code after it. In this case the `return "maintenance/menu";`.

Comment: on the server side it only send headers to tell browser to make another http request.

Comment: Why wouldn't it execute it? It's just Java. Calling a method won't halt the execution of the calling method, unless the called method throws an exception.

Comment: @holi-java Your edit was the real solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal java code after all, after the control is done with processing the "sendRedirect()" it will continue the execution.